# "Formal argument "foo" matched by multiple arguments" - how to deal with this in R?

Tags: r, function, plot, arguments

Sometimes, calling a function with certain arguments results in the error message `formal argument "foo" matched by multiple actual arguments`. Is it possible to print the list of the ambiguous actual arguments?

The reason I'm asking this is currently a problem with the `plot` function for objects of class `mixEM` (generated by `normalmixEM` from the `mixtools` package). It doesn't accept the argument `ylim` yielding the error above, but when I try to use `ylim2` (the way it works for `xlab2`, `main2`, `col2` etc.), it says `"ylim2" is not a graphical parameter`. So I wonder what are the actual arguments that are matched by `ylim`?

Using `formals(plot.mixEM)` doesn't help because it doesn't contain anything starting with `ylim`, but then at the end it refers to `...` which are the graphical parameters passed to `plot`. However, for the `plot` function, `ylim` would be unambiguous. Getting a more exact error description from `R` with a list of the conflicting arguments would be helpful.

UPD: MWE:

```
library(mixtools)
wait = faithful$waiting
mixmdl = normalmixEM(wait)
plot(mixmdl, which = 2, xlim = c(25, 110), nclass=20)
lines(density(wait), lty = 2, lwd = 2)
```

This produces an error:

```
plot(mixmdl, which = 2, xlim = c(25, 110), ylim = c(0, .5), nclass=20)

# Error in hist.default(x, prob = TRUE, main = main2, xlab = xlab2, ylim = c(0, :
# formal argument "ylim" matched by multiple actual arguments`
```

This simply doesn't work:

```
plot(mixmdl, which = 2, xlim = c(25, 110), ylim2 = c(0, .5), nclass=20)

# Warning messages:
# 1: In title(main = main, sub = sub, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, ...) :
#   "ylim2" is not a graphical parameter
# 2: In axis(1, ...) : "ylim2" is not a graphical parameter
# 3: In axis(2, ...) : "ylim2" is not a graphical parameter
```

Comment: It is easier to add the code that produce the error than the narrative way ...

Comment: @agstudy I've added a MWE. However, I would also appreciate a general advice on how to deal with this kind of errors, because this is not the first and probably not the last time I encounter this type of problems.

Comment: FYI - this error can also occur if you accidentally add an argument to a function call twice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is essentially of type:

```
plot(1:10, rnorm(10), ylim=c(0,1), ylim=c(-1,100))
Error in plot.default(1:10, rnorm(10), ylim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(-1, 100)) : 
  formal argument "ylim" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

because your *ylim*-definition gets passed on to a plot function with the "..."-argument, in the following line of *plot.mixEM*:

```
hist(x, prob = TRUE, main = main2, xlab = xlab2, ylim = c(0, maxy), ...)
```

while *ylim* has been defined with the following upper limit:

```
maxy <- max(max(a$density), 0.3989 * mix.object$lambda/mix.object$sigma)
```

Notice that you are calling plotting function for an object of type *mixEM*. Looking at the code of the default plotting function *plot.default* will leave you puzzled, as it is actually *plot.mixEM* that you are calling. If you type *plot.mixEM* in the terminal you will see its code, and *?plot.mixEM* will help you out as well. This is a typical approach in R, where the default function *functionname.default* is replaced by a class-specific function provided by the package in the format *functionname.classname*.

You got couple options:

1. Write your own *plot.mixEM* by replacing the hard-coded part in the
   original function, you only need to change couple lines.
2. Plot the window before *plot.mixEM* and add the "*add=TRUE*" parameter, which means that we will not create a new plotting window but instead add to the existing one.

This is how option 2 works:

```
library(mixtools)
wait = faithful$waiting
mixmdl = normalmixEM(wait)
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=c(25,110), ylim=c(0,0.5))
plot(mixmdl, which = 2, nclass=20, add = TRUE)
lines(density(wait), lty = 2, lwd = 2)
box(); axis(1); axis(2); title(xlab="Data", ylab="Density")
```

[image: Example plot]

Answer (score 3):

```
library(mixtools)
wait = faithful$waiting
mixmdl = normalmixEM(wait)

plot(mixmdl, which = 2, xlim = c(25, 110), ylim = c(0, .5), nclass=20)
#Error in hist.default(x, prob = TRUE, main = main2, xlab = xlab2, ylim = c(0,  : 
#  formal argument "ylim" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

The error message is quite informative. It tells you which function gets passed the parameter twice. For more information:

```
traceback()

# 4: hist.default(x, prob = TRUE, main = main2, xlab = xlab2, ylim = c(0, 
#                                                                      maxy), ...)
# 3: hist(x, prob = TRUE, main = main2, xlab = xlab2, ylim = c(0, 
#                                                              maxy), ...)
# 2: plot.mixEM(mixmdl, which = 2, xlim = c(25, 110), ylim = c(0, 
#                                                              0.5), nclass = 20)
# 1: plot(mixmdl, which = 2, xlim = c(25, 110), ylim = c(0, 0.5), 
#         nclass = 20)
```

So, there is a call to `hist` in `plot.mixEM` that already sets `ylim = c(0,maxy)`. Your `ylim = c(0,0.5)` gets passed via the ellipsis (`...`), so that `hist.default` gets passed `ylim` twice. Hence, the error.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But why doesn't the `ylim` in my call overwrite the default values set by `plot.mixEM`? And how can I change it?

Comment: Because of the ellipses. Define your own plotting function (copy the code from `plot.mixEM` and remove `ylim=c(0,maxy)` from the offending call to `hist`).