# Manually set fontsize of axis titles in native-R plot and lattice graphing functions

Tags: r

I am trying to prepare a graph for a poster presentation, but am getting very frustrated by how difficult things that should be simple are in `plot`. I want to plot a qq-plot of residuals from a mixed-effects model. All I want to do is change the font size of the axis title

. Here's a reproducible example.

```
library(lme4)
library(lattice)



fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)

qqmath(fm1,
       main = list("QQ-Plot", cex = 2),
       id=0.05, 
       cex = list(x = 2),
       scales = list(x = list(cex = 2), y = list(cex = 2)))
```

This all works fine. But when I try to increase the font size of the axis title

```
qqmath(fm1,
       main = list("QQ-Plot", cex = 2),
       xlab = list("x-axis", cex = 2),
       id=0.05, 
       cex = list(x = 2),
       scales = list(x = list(cex = 2), y = list(cex = 2)))
```

I get

```
Error in qqmath.formula(x = ~x, ylab = "Standardized residuals", xlab = "Standard normal quantiles",  : 
  formal argument "xlab" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

I gather from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650346/formal-argument-foo-matched-by-multiple-arguments-how-to-deal-with-this-in) post that this is due to competing arguments in the function call and some ellipsis in the original `qqmath.formula` object, but surely there *has* to be an easier way to set the fontsize of the axis titles than reprogramming the original function?!

Comment: If you type: `methods(qqmath)` you should see that qqmath.formula is probably not the function being called. And after looking at the code of the one I think is more likely being dispatched by `lmer`, I suspect that your confidence in there being a simpler method to relabel the y-axis is misplaced. You _should_ include the needed `library` calls. The goal is also unclear : is it font size or text of hte label that should be changed?

Comment: Font size. The text itself is unimportant. Do you mean `library(lattice)` and `library(lme4)`?

Comment: I meant _both_.

Comment: I have added the library calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lattice system has functions `trellis.par.get` and `trellis.par.set` and this can be used to control the fontsize of the xlab and ylab components:

```
?trellis.par.get
 names( trellis.par.get() )
 trellis.par.set(par.ylab.text=list(cex=.5))
 qqmath(fm1,
       main = list("QQ-Plot", cex = 2),       id=0.05, 
       cex=list(left=.55,bottom=.5), 
       scales = list(x = list(cex = 1), y = list(cex = 1)))
```

... reduces the size of the ylab. You can find a more complete list of the components and features that can be set from a chart onpage 127 in the "Lattice" book by Sarkar.